# State true or false: vectoriel space

Tags: vectors

Hello can someone tell me, please, if I anwered the questions correctly.

1- **false**: The set of rational numbers with the usual addition and multiplication operations by a scalar is a vector space on the real ones.

2-**True**: All polynomials of degree greater than or equal to 3 with the usual operations are a vector space.

[image]

Comment: 2- What about the zero polynomial? 1- is okay, though.

Comment: My mistake for the second question. Does the ones in the picture correct?

Comment: What operations are you talking about? The usual ones? What are the $P_k$? Spaces of polynomials? Then the two “affine” ones (first and fourth) are wrong, as their set is not stable under addition.

Answer (score 1):

1)

W = {(x, x+1)} is not a subspace of R^2. One reason is that (2,3)+(2,3) = (4,6) is not in W, so it is not closed under addition. Another reason could be that (0,0) is not in W.

2)

W = {p(x) : p(x) in P_n and p(3) = 0}.

These are all single variable polynomials of degree at most n (over some field) that have a factor of (x-3). Note that if you add or scale such polynomials it will still have a factor of (x-3). Note also that the 0 polynomial satisfies 0(3) = 0. So yes, it is a subspace of P_n.

3)

W = {p(x) : p(x) in P_4 and p(2) = 3}

The constant polynomial 3 is in W and 3(2) = 3 by virtue of it being constant.

On the other hand 3+3 = 6 does not satisfy 6(2) = 3, so W is not closed under addition.

Thus W is not a vector subspace of P_4. An easier argument is simply to note that the origin of P_4, i.e. the 0 polynomial, is not an element of W.

Do the rest yourself. A subspace of a vector space V is a subset that is closed under addition, scalar multiplication, and contains the original origin.

Comment: Rando, I am just super not good at algebra. I am trying for real. The last question I found true.

Comment: "subspace" has a definition. So does "vector space". If you don't know the definition well, then what is the point of doing these problems? If you just want a grade in your class, then sure. But you won't learn anything and you won't develop any skills. If you want to develop skills, you have to learn the hard way. There's no way around it. Sorry :(